# Why is Microsoft Solver Foundation not returning a solution?

Tags: linear-programming, ms-solver-foundation

I'm trying to solve my linear program with Microsoft Solver Foundation, but it doesn't return a solution. It doesn't give a clear message to what is wrong, so I'm not sure what is going on. I have checked the constraints and I believe they are coded correctly, but maybe the LP model is wrong on itself? I would be glad if you can take a look at it and see what's wrong :)

```
===Solver Foundation Service Report===
Date: 15/10/2021 16:00:21
Version: Microsoft Solver Foundation 3.0.2.10889 Express Edition
Model Name: DefaultModel
Capabilities Applied: MILP
Solve Time (ms): 51
Total Time (ms): 103
Solve Completion Status: Unknown
Solver Selected: Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Solvers.SimplexSolver
Directives:
Simplex(TimeLimit = -1, MaximumGoalCount = -1, Arithmetic = Default, Pricing = Default, IterationLimit = -1, Algorithm = Default, Basis = Default, GetSensitivity = False)
Algorithm: Primal
Arithmetic: Exact
Variables: 133 -> 133 + 40
Rows: 40 -> 40
Nonzeros: 522
Eliminated Slack Variables: 0
Basis: Slack
Pivot Count: 0
Phase 1 Pivots: 0 + 0
Phase 2 Pivots: 0 + 0
Factorings: 0 + 0
Degenerate Pivots: 0 (0,00 %)
Branches: 0
```

I'm making this for a practical assignment, so I prefer not to share my code. For information about the assignment: it's a machine assignment problem, where you have to plan two appointments for all patients. There are global parameters:

- **p1**: the duration of the first appointment
- **p2**: the duration of the second appointment
- **g**: the gap between the first and second appointment

Each patient needs two appointments **t1** and **t2** that need to be planned. Each patient also has personal parameters:

- interval **I1=[r1, d1]**, the time interval in which the first appointment can be planned
- **x**: (personal) extra gap between the first and second appointment
- length **l**, the length of the second time interval. **I2=[t1 + p1 + g + x, t1 + p1 + g + x + l - 1]**

[image: LP model1]

Comment: It says "Solve Completion Status: Unknown". Note that Solver Foundation has been discontinued a very long time ago. Better use a more recent tool.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I saw that, but I don't know what that means. Normally it would just say No solution or something, this message is very unclear to me.